# Cannot browse website from web server local network

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, web-server

I have an web server where I have hosted my domains. Also I am using the same network to my home. But I can not see my domains from the same network. I have to use different internet service to access that. WHat should I do now?

Comment: Start checking DNS results, firewalls, etc. Hard to say what the issue is - you haven't given us many details about your setup.

Comment: What sort of details should you need? I can give all.

Comment: Do you have firewalls? Do you have internal DNS in your network? What do `dig`, `ping`, etc. against the domain in question result in?

Comment: Yes I have firewall Pfsense. I don't have internal DNS in the network.

Comment: Does your firewall have *rules* that would affect this traffic? Are you just going to skip over the `dig` / `ping` question? You need to do some troubleshooting here.

Comment: When I tried to browse this came Index of /
[ICO] Name Last modified Size Description
Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at www.eco2.ca Port 80

Answer (score -1):

Kindly enter the IP behind your domain on ping.pe or maplatency.com. It will tell you whether your web server is reachable through all the well known ISPs around the world or not. If you see a latency or loss or reachablity issue kindly contact your datacenter with a screenshot of Proof.